# Updating post status via rest api

Tags: posts, rest-api, post-status

I am attempting to remove/hide a post via the REST API and having issues.

Currently, I have tried sending the payload as:

```
{
    'status':'private'
}
```

And I send the request to:

```
/wp/v2/posts/<id here>
```

Every other part of my requirements works. I am able to create a post and update post content, but now I want to remove a post without deleting it, but it doesn't seem like I can update the status. I remembered reading that the payload needs to include title, content, and excerpt, so I tried another request with those and that didn't work either.

I suppose I could fully delete the post if I need to, but this would work better for my needs. Does anyone know how to accomplish this or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What result do you get back from the API? It might be helpful to add the code to show how you're calling the API to your question. Going by the docs your request looks ok. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#update-a-post

Comment: I added in the code to print the response and it came back 200, and for some reason, it worked this time. I have no idea why...